# How can I store the result of a SQL query in a CSV file using Squirrel?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, squirrel-sql

Version 3.0.3.  It's a fairly large result-set, around 3 million rows.

Comment: What kind of database is it? Some databases already have abilities to write to output files.

Comment: i know i can do it using the cmdline, but id like to be able to do it from the graphical interface

Answer (score 34):

Martin pretty much has this right.

The TL/DR version is that you need the "SQLScripts" plugin (which is one of the "standard' plugins), and then you can select these menu options: `Session` > `Scripts` > `Store Result of SQL in File`

I'm looking at version 3.4. I don't know when this feature was introduced but you may need to upgrade if you don't have and cannot install the SQLScripts plugin.

Instructions for installing a new plugin can be found at: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/user-manual/quick_start.html#plugins

But if you're performing a fresh install of Squirrel you can simply select the "SQLScripts" plugin during the installation.

Here's the long version:

---

1. **Run the query**

   Connect to the database.  Click on the `SQL` tab. Enter your query.  Hit the run button (or `Ctrl-Enter`).

   You should see the first 100 rows or so in the results area in the bottom half of the pane (depending upon how you've configured the `Limit Rows` option).
2. **Export the *full* results**

   Open the `Session` menu. Select the `Scripts` item (nearly at the bottom of this long menu).  Select `Store Result of SQL in File`.

   This opens a dialog box where you can configure your export.  Make sure you check `Export the complete result set` to get everything.

---

I haven't tried this with a 3 million row result set, but I have noticed that Squirrel seems to stream the data to disk (rather than reading it all into memory before writing), so I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with an arbitrarily large file.

Note that you can export directly to a file by using `Ctrl-T` to invoke the tools popup and selecting `sql2file`.

Comment: Just a quick update: Yesterday I happen to have used this feature to export about 8 million rows from a data warehouse schema.  Squirrel/SQLScripts worked like a champ.

Comment: When I try "Store Result of SQL in File" it returns "Method not supported"

Comment: I feel like they are trying to hide it!

Answer (score 5):

I have found a way to do this, there is a nice support for this in Squirrel. Run the SQL select (the 100 row limit will be ignored by the exporter, don't worry). Then, in the main menu, choose Session, Scripts, Store Result of SQL in File. This functionality may not be present by default, it may be present in some standard plugin (but not installed by default). I don't know which plugin though.

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to export results of SQL query to CSV file using SquirrelSQL. However according to [changes file](http://squirrel-sql.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/squirrel-sql/trunk/sql12/doc/src/main/resources/changes.txt) it seems that this functionality is not supported even in SquirrelSql 3.3.0.

So far I was able to export only data shown in 'result table' of SQL query by right click on the table > Export to CSV. The table size is by default 100 rows and so is the CSV export. You may change the table size in Session Properties > SQL > Limit rows. E.g. change the size to 10000 and your export will also contain 10000 rows. The question is, how will SquirrelSql deal with really big result sets (millions of rows)...

Answer (score 2):

Run from your GUI:

`COPY (SELECT * FROM some_table) TO '/some/path/some_table.csv' WITH CSV HEADER`

Comment: Note that this will run the copy process on the *server*. So if it's a remote server, the file will be dumped on that server, and not your local machine. Likewise, you need to make sure that the server process has write permissions there. You can use \copy instead of copy to get it on the client side if you use psql - not sure if squirrel has anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Squirrel 3.5.0
The "Store SQL result as file" is great if you only have a simple Select query. A more complex one with parameters wont work.
Even trying to export a result of 600,000+ rows to a CSV file can also fail.